# fixed images on image with specific coordinates, ratio?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I managed to have an image on my website where by hovering the mouse on specific places, it appends other images in absolute position in these spaces.

Here is how it looks like before:

[image]

Here is how it looks like after hovering the mouse on the spaces:

[image]

The only problem is when I resize my window with a smaller width, the images are not placed the way they are in larger width:

[image]

As you can see the images overstep the background image.

Here is the script I implemented:

```
$(function() {
$(".mycinetik-image").find("img").mousemove(function(e) {
  var offset = $(this).offset();
  var relativeX = (e.pageX - offset.left);
  var relativeY = (e.pageY - offset.top);
  var taillePhotoX = $(this).outerWidth();
  var taillePhotoY = $(this).outerHeight();
  var widthImage1 = (taillePhotoX/1.591) - (taillePhotoX/8);
  var widthImage2 = (taillePhotoX/2.683) - (taillePhotoX/8.7);
  var heightImage1 = (taillePhotoY/1.56) - (taillePhotoY/24.84);
  var heightImage2 = (taillePhotoY/1.067) - (taillePhotoY/1.56);
  if((relativeX >= taillePhotoX/7) && (relativeX <= taillePhotoX/1.6) && (relativeY <= taillePhotoY/1.59) && (relativeY >= taillePhotoY/13.1)){
    appendImgMyCinetik (1, taillePhotoX/7.75, taillePhotoY/23, widthImage1, heightImage1);
  } 
  else if((relativeX >= taillePhotoX/7) && (relativeX <= taillePhotoX/2.5) && (relativeY <= taillePhotoY/1.084) && (relativeY >= taillePhotoY/1.514)){
    appendImgMyCinetik (2, taillePhotoX/7.5, taillePhotoY/1.56, widthImage2, heightImage2);
  } 
  else if((relativeX >= taillePhotoX/2.5) && (relativeX <= taillePhotoX/1.6) && (relativeY <= taillePhotoY/1.084) && (relativeY >= taillePhotoY/1.514)){
    appendImgMyCinetik (3, taillePhotoX/2.6, taillePhotoY/1.56, widthImage2, heightImage2);
  } 
  else if((relativeX >= taillePhotoX/1.55) && (relativeX <= taillePhotoX/1.01) && (relativeY <= taillePhotoY/1.084) && (relativeY >= taillePhotoY/1.514)){
    appendImgMyCinetik (4, taillePhotoX/1.586, taillePhotoY/1.56, widthImage2, heightImage2);
  }
  else if((relativeX >= taillePhotoX/1.6) && (relativeX <= taillePhotoX/1.01) && (relativeY <= taillePhotoY/1.59) && (relativeY >= taillePhotoY/13.1)){
    appendImgMyCinetik (5, taillePhotoX/1.586, taillePhotoY/20, widthImage2, heightImage1);
  }
});
});

function appendImgMyCinetik (nb, x, y, imgWidth, imgHeight){
if(nb == 1 && ($("#" + nb).length == 0)){
    var newImg= '<img  id="1" style="position:absolute; top:'+ y +'px; left:'+ x +'px; width:'+ imgWidth +'px; height:'+ imgHeight +'px; opacity:0;" src="img/appart1.png">';
    $(".mycinetik-image").append(newImg);
    $("#1").animate({
        opacity:1
    }, 500 );
}else if(nb == 2 && ($("#" + nb).length == 0)){
    var newImg= '<img  id="2" style="position:absolute; top:'+ y +'px; left:'+ x +'px; width:'+ imgWidth +'px; height:'+ imgHeight +'px; opacity:0;" src="img/appart2.png">';
    $(".mycinetik-image").append(newImg);
    $("#2").animate({
        opacity:1
    }, 500 );
}else if(nb == 3 && ($("#" + nb).length == 0)){
    var newImg= '<img  id="3" style="position:absolute; top:'+ y +'px; left:'+ x +'px; width:'+ imgWidth +'px; height:'+ imgHeight +'px; opacity:0;" src="img/appart3.png">';
    $(".mycinetik-image").append(newImg);
    $("#3").animate({
        opacity:1
    }, 500 );
}else if(nb == 4 && ($("#" + nb).length == 0)){
    var newImg= '<img  id="4" style="position:absolute; top:'+ y +'px; left:'+ x +'px; width:'+ imgWidth +'px; height:'+ imgHeight +'px; opacity:0;" src="img/appart4.png">';
    $(".mycinetik-image").append(newImg);
    $("#4").animate({
        opacity:1
    }, 500 );
}else if(nb == 5 && ($("#" + nb).length == 0)){
    var newImg= '<img  id="5" style="position:absolute; top:'+ y +'px; left:'+ x +'px; width:'+ imgWidth +'px; height:'+ imgHeight +'px; opacity:0;" src="img/appart5.png">';
    $(".mycinetik-image").append(newImg);
    $("#5").animate({
        opacity:1
    }, 500 );
}
}
```

I use ratios to adapt the image size to the screen width but weirdly, the smaller my window width is, the higher the overstep is.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Please add a fiddle or snippet with all your code. What you want is not clear.

Comment: I just can't... It's a huge project

Comment: ok also please more details of your issue.

Comment: I'm still unclear about what exactly you're asking. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to answer with this little information. You mentioned that you use ratios to adapt the image size, but your function is using fixed sizes in pixels

```
'width:'+ imgWidth +'px;'
```

I see you are assigning the width values with:

```
var taillePhotoX = $(this).outerWidth();
```

but this isn't relative to the window size. it depends on the image and that will be constant across different windows.

You could use:

```
var taillePhotoX = $(window).width() // * (times) proportion ratio calculation;
```

To make it relative to the browser window.

Additionally, if you have a finite number of overlapping images (your code only considers 5), you could use classes to define the way they should look across different screen sizes including transitions. Then, have the function to simply assign the appropriate class accordingly.

Comment: Didn't think about classes with media queries ! thanks bro